# use Browserify-shim with Laravel Elixir-Browserify

Tags: laravel-elixir, browserify-shim

I have install the browserify-shim using `npm` as usual. And configured the package.json as per its manual. I am not sure how it goes with Laravel-elixir. Bacause the way I see it, I don't want to specify the `main` file in package.json because I have directly specify the entry file in the gulpFile.js. So far I have no luck in getting my non Commonjs file to be shim with browserify.

What is the way to go for this? Any one ever wonder about this?